# Unable to establish internet connection for my Windows 10 VM through Hyper-V Virtual Switch

Tags: hyper-v

I'm using the Hyper-V's Virtual Switch Manager & trying to set-up an External Virtual Network using my Wireless Adapter, but once I click apply, it kicks off the internet connection on the host machine itself. Had been trying for hours with no much success.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue most of the time whenever i setup a new virtual machine. One of the solution over the web is the following

- **Make a new Virtual Network Switch**

1. Turn off your Windows 10 virtual machine.
2. Open the Hyper-V Manager -> click on the Virtual Switch Manager option found in the panel to your right.
3. In the newly opened window -> click New virtual network switch found in the left-side panel.
4. From the right-side panel -> choose External -> Create virtual switch.
5. Inside the Virtual Switch Properties window -> change the name of your virtual machine.
6. Under the Connection type section -> choose External network -> Realtek PCIe GBE Familly Controller.
7. Check the box next to Allow management operating system to share this network adapter -> press Ok.

- **Set the configuration parameters for the network adapter**

1. Inside your Virtual Machine Manager -> scroll down in the right-side panel -> click Settings in the Windows 10 section.
2. Choose Network Adapter from the left-side panel -> toggle the drop-down Virtual Switch menu -> choose the switch created in Method 1 -> press Ok to save the settings.

- **Set up your Network Connection to share it with Hyper-V**

1. On your host Windows 10 machine -> right-click the Network icon found next to your Windows clock -> click Open Network & Internet Settings.
2. In the Status tab -> click on Change adapter options.
   Inside the Network Connections window -> right-click your
3. In the Sharing tab -> enable the Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection option -> choose the network switch created earlier -> press Ok -> turn on Windows 10 in Hyper-V to finish the fix method.

Note: *if in case the above solution not works then try disable the virtual machine firewall.*